# Grpc protoc configuration cannot upgrade to latest version with gradle 7.0 but possible in gradle 4.2

Tags: android, gradle, grpc

This is my protoc setup in build.gradle which works in gradle 4.2

```
protobuf {
    protoc { artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.10.0' }
    plugins {
        javalite { artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0" }
        grpc { artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.25.0' // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.plugins {
                javalite {}
                grpc { // Options added to --grpc_out
                    option 'lite' }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How is it not building in only gradle 7.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `protoc` setup for as described in the current documentation is:

```
protobuf {
    protoc { artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.12.0' }
    plugins {
        grpc { artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.36.0' // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java { option 'lite' }
            }
            task.plugins {
                grpc { // Options added to --grpc_out
                    option 'lite' }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main difference from what you have is the lack of definition in `task.plugins` and setting mode `'lite'` and using the [grpc-java](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/java/quickstart/) library and not the java-lite.

Comment: This worked for me thanks. Turns out I was following an outdated tutorial.